# How to modify nodes style and not change the position

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I have a diagram where I want to overlay a layer of thick red on top of the original black color. The problem is that as I add the very thick option the nodes get increasingly more displaced.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, shadows, arrows, positioning}

\tikzstyle{agent} = [diamond, draw, node distance= 7em, minimum height=5em, minimum width=5em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -stealth]
\tikzstyle{inp} = [draw, circle, text centered, minimum height=2mm, text width=2em, node distance= 10em]
\tikzstyle{outp} = [draw, ellipse, text centered, minimum height=2mm, text width=2em, node distance= 10em]


\newcommand{\asd}[1]{

}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{adjustbox}{max totalsize={1\textwidth}{.8\textheight},center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

%%%%%Researcher 1 and Inputs: depends on R_1%%%%%%%
\node [inp](R_1){R};
\node [inp, left of=R_1, xshift=15em](D_1){D};
\node [agent, below of=D_1](Researcher_1){$R_1$};
\node [agent, below =5em of Researcher_1](PA_1){$PA_1$};
\node [agent, below =6em of PA_1](PM_1){$PM_1$};
\node [outp, below = 3.5em of PM_1](PC_1){$PC_1$};
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%% Draw edges col 1%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Research 1
\draw [line](D_1) -- (Researcher_1);
\draw [line](R_1) -- (Researcher_1);
\draw [line](Researcher_1) -- (PA_1);
\draw [line](PA_1) -- (PM_1);
\draw [line](PM_1) -- (PC_1);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\node [inp, color=red, very thick](R_1){R};
\draw [line, color=red, very thick](R_1) -- (Researcher_1);
\node [agent, below of=D_1, color=red, very thick](Researcher_1){$R_1$}; 
\draw [line, color=red, very thick](Researcher_1) -- (PA_1);
\node [agent, below =5em of Researcher_1 , color=red, very thick](PA_1){$PA_1$};
\draw [line, color=red, very thick](PA_1) -- (PM_1);
\node [agent, below =6em of PA_1, color=red, very thick](PM_1){$PM_1$};
\draw [line, color=red, very thick](PM_1) -- (PC_1);
\node [outp, below = 3.5em of PM_1, color=red, very thick](PC_1){$PC_1$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Can you tell where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `outer sep` of nodes is initially `.5\pgflinewidth`. So it depends on the thickness of the border line of the node.

One possibility is to use a fixed value for `outer sep` for the whole picture:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=.2pt]
```

Result:

[image]